# How can I share a Cisco VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, internet-sharing

I am using ICS on my Early 2011 MBP (latest version of Snow Leopard) to share a connection to various devices, e.g. XBOX.

Normally this is by manually configuring the network settings on the client, and connecting to the MBP via Ethernet.

I can share the Airport connection wifi fine, but when I connect to a VPN using Cisco client it does not work. The Cisco adapter seems to be hidden when trying to select it as a source option for ICS.

Any possibility to recreate the Cisco connection using Native mac client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this option was also available in Snow Leopard, but if you are on Lion you could try the following:

1. Set up the native cisco client - if you don't know how, you can use [this handy guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17823/how-can-i-make-the-cisco-vpn-client-work-with-lion/18511#18511) I created a few days back
2. Once you have tried and confirmed that everything works, your VPN connection should show up as one of the options in the *Internet Sharing* part of Preferences Sharing.
3. select the connection, choose on which network connection you'd like to share it and you're done.

[image: share vpn connection]

Comment: Thanks! It is available in SL, and after a day of faffing, I found out the Apple built in support is not for UDP, only TCP. Not sure if Lion changes that?